# How long does one get to keep the third bean field in bohnanza?

Tags: bohnanza

Does the third field stay forever once you have 3 coins to buy it? If not when does it disappear? The rules aren't terribly clear (or maybe I should say "are terribly clear").

Comment: Well, it doesn't stay forever - it disappears at the end of the game!  It would be a terrible rip-off if disappeared earlier (e.g. when you harvested the beans in it), it's very debatable if it's worth buying as things stand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You keep the third bean field for the duration of the game.  It would be harsh if it was limited as it does cost you 3 gold coins (victory points).

Here is a discussion about [when to buy or not buy that third field](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/when-should-you-avoid-a-third-bean-field-in-bohnanza).  Due to the cost, it is not always the right thing to do to purchase the field.